# Show more/less toggle doesn't show everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code below that consist of 2 list `Total Fruits and Random Fruits` and i'm able to move the values from one list to another and vice versa. The problem is after i add all the fruits from `Random fruits to Total fruits`and click the show more button it is not able to show the full list.

I'm not really sure what is causing this problem any help / suggestion would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```js
var redpill = {};
var greenpill = {};
var randompill = {};


var key = "Red Fruits";
redpill[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry', 'Pomegranate', 'Rassberry', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'];

var key2 = "Green Fruits";
greenpill[key2] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'];

var key3 = "Random Fruits";
randompill[key3] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'];

function redraw() {
  var combineString = '';
  $.each(redpill[key], function(index) {
    combineString += ('<div class="pilldiv redpill class">' + redpill[key][index] + '</div>');
  });
  $('.combineclass').html(combineString);

  $.each(greenpill[key2], function(index) {
    combineString += ('<div class="pilldiv greenpill class">' + greenpill[key2][index] + '</div>');
  });
  $('.combineclass').html(combineString);

  var randomString = '';
  $.each(randompill[key3], function(index) {
    randomString += ('<div class="pilldiv randompill class">' + randompill[key3][index] + '</div>');
  });
  $('.randomclass').html(randomString);
}

function listener() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#suggestid div", function() {
      data = this.innerHTML;
      $(".total_count_Green_Fruits").html(key2 + ': ' + greenpill[key2].length);
      var element = $(this).detach();
      $('#currentid').prepend('<div class="new-green-fruit pilldiv class ">' + element.html() + '</div>');
    });
  });

  $('body').on('click', 'div.new-green-fruit', function() {
    data2 = this.innerHTML;
    $(this).detach();
    var element2 = $(this).detach();
    $('#suggestid').prepend('<div class="pilldiv randompill class" >' + element2.html() + '</div>');
  });
}
redraw();
listener();

var slideHeight = 100;
$(".container").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $wrap = $this.children(".wrapper");
  var defHeight = $wrap.height();
  if (defHeight >= slideHeight) {
    var $readMore = $this.find(".read-more");
    $wrap.css("height", slideHeight + "px");
    $readMore.append("<a href='#'>Show More</a>");
    $readMore.children("a").bind("click", function(event) {
      var curHeight = $wrap.height();
      if (curHeight == slideHeight) {
        $wrap.animate({
          height: defHeight
        }, "normal");
        $(this).text("Show Less");
        $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeOut();
      } else {
        $wrap.animate({
          height: slideHeight
        }, "normal");
        $(this).text("Show More");
        $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeIn();
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.pilldiv {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: Black;
  margin: 2px;
}

.randompill:after {
  content: "\002B";
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
}

.new-green-fruit:after {
  content: "\292B";
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
}

.redpill {
  background-color: Pink;
  cursor: default;
}

.greenpill {
  background-color: SpringGreen;
  cursor: default;
}

.randompill {
  background-color: LightBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.panel {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.new-green-fruit {
  background-color: LightBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#leftpanel {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  "

}

#rightpanel {
  float: right;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  "

}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.gradient {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background: url(http://spoonfedproject.com/wp-content/uploads/demo/jquer-slide/images/bg-gradient.png) repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.read-more {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
}

.read-more a {
  padding-right: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.read-more a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id=leftpanel>
        <h3 class="class center">Total Fruits</h3>
        <div id="currentid" class="combineclass wrappingflexbox top"></div>

        <div class="gradient">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="rightpanel">
        <h3 class="class center">Random Fruits</h3>
        <div id="suggestid" class="randomclass wrappingflexbox top"></div>

        <div class="gradient">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="read-more">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: works for me, not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @JeromeIndefenzo Try adding everything into the other list first and click the show more button it doesn't show everything. It will push the original value below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this problem is happening because are setting fixed heights onto your panels with an overflow hidden. Try setting `overflow: scroll` on your `wrapper` class as shown in the snippet below.

**EDIT:**

It actually seems to perform better when you completely remove `overflow` from `wrapper`

```js
var redpill = {};
var greenpill = {};
var randompill = {};


var key = "Red Fruits";
redpill[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry', 'Pomegranate', 'Rassberry', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'];

var key2 = "Green Fruits";
greenpill[key2] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'];

var key3 = "Random Fruits";
randompill[key3] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew', 'Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado', 'Lime', 'Honeydew'];

function redraw() {
  var combineString = '';
  $.each(redpill[key], function(index) {
    combineString += ('<div class="pilldiv redpill class">' + redpill[key][index] + '</div>');
  });
  $('.combineclass').html(combineString);

  $.each(greenpill[key2], function(index) {
    combineString += ('<div class="pilldiv greenpill class">' + greenpill[key2][index] + '</div>');
  });
  $('.combineclass').html(combineString);

  var randomString = '';
  $.each(randompill[key3], function(index) {
    randomString += ('<div class="pilldiv randompill class">' + randompill[key3][index] + '</div>');
  });
  $('.randomclass').html(randomString);
}

function listener() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#suggestid div", function() {
      data = this.innerHTML;
      $(".total_count_Green_Fruits").html(key2 + ': ' + greenpill[key2].length);
      var element = $(this).detach();
      $('#currentid').prepend('<div class="new-green-fruit pilldiv class ">' + element.html() + '</div>');
    });
  });

  $('body').on('click', 'div.new-green-fruit', function() {
    data2 = this.innerHTML;
    $(this).detach();
    var element2 = $(this).detach();
    $('#suggestid').prepend('<div class="pilldiv randompill class" >' + element2.html() + '</div>');
  });
}
redraw();
listener();

var slideHeight = 100;
$(".container").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $wrap = $this.children(".wrapper");
  var defHeight = $wrap.height();
  if (defHeight >= slideHeight) {
    var $readMore = $this.find(".read-more");
    $wrap.css("height", slideHeight + "px");
    $readMore.append("<a href='#'>Show More</a>");
    $readMore.children("a").bind("click", function(event) {
      var curHeight = $wrap.height();
      if (curHeight == slideHeight) {
        $wrap.animate({
          height: defHeight
        }, "normal");
        $(this).text("Show Less");
        $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeOut();
      } else {
        $wrap.animate({
          height: slideHeight
        }, "normal");
        $(this).text("Show More");
        $wrap.children(".gradient").fadeIn();
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.pilldiv {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: Black;
  margin: 2px;
}

.randompill:after {
  content: "\002B";
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
}

.new-green-fruit:after {
  content: "\292B";
  float: left;
  width: 16px;
}

.redpill {
  background-color: Pink;
  cursor: default;
}

.greenpill {
  background-color: SpringGreen;
  cursor: default;
}

.randompill {
  background-color: LightBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrappingflexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.panel {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.new-green-fruit {
  background-color: LightBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#leftpanel {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  "

}

#rightpanel {
  float: right;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  "

}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}

.gradient {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background: url(http://spoonfedproject.com/wp-content/uploads/demo/jquer-slide/images/bg-gradient.png) repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.read-more {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
}

.read-more a {
  padding-right: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.read-more a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id=leftpanel>
        <h3 class="class center">Total Fruits</h3>
        <div id="currentid" class="combineclass wrappingflexbox top"></div>

        <div class="gradient">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="rightpanel">
        <h3 class="class center">Random Fruits</h3>
        <div id="suggestid" class="randomclass wrappingflexbox top"></div>

        <div class="gradient">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="read-more">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is it looks quite weird with the scrollbar is there no way to make it so that when i click the show more button the list will fully extend?

Comment: With overflow on the wrapper it can only extend as big as the wrapper. You could try setting the wrapper to have a min-height instead of a fixed height, or you could even remove overflow from the wrapper.

Comment: because im not really sure how to edit this code im getting this code from an example on stack